# Как изменить свойство виджета color на значение, находящееся в переменной?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class LearnPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  Color color;
  Icon icon;
  String name;
  String text;
  LearnPoint({this.color, this.icon, this.name, this.text});
  this.icon.color = Colors.amber; //<------ что -то типа вот этого
  @override
  //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stateful и Stateless виджеты**

Конкретно под ваши нужды, необходимо использовать Stateful.

Например:

```
class SimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _SimpleWidgetState createState() => _SimpleWidgetState();

}

class _SimpleWidgetState extends State<SimpleWidget> {

    Color backgroundColor = Colors.yellow;

    changeColor()
    {
        setState(() {
            backgroundColor = Colors.grey;
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: Text("Простой виджет"),
        );
    }
}
```

При вызове метода changeColor(), изменяется значение переменной и перерисовывается виджет, благодаря setState(...).

Более подробно описано [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/424765/).